# Freemarker Template else clause not getting executed

Tags: java, freemarker

I am using freemarker template engine for creating dyxml package structure. In Java, a tree structure is getting created which is being rendered using ftl. I have the following code in my ftl file -

```
    <dyxml:root>
        <#list nodes as outerNode>
        <dyxml:node id="${outerNode.getNodeId()}" name="${outerNode.title}">
            <#if outerNode?size !=0>
                <#list outerNode.children as innerNode>
                <dyxml:node id="${innerNode.getNodeId()}" name="${innerNode.title}">
                    <#if innerNode?size !=0>
                        <#list innerNode.children as grandChildNode>
                        <dyxml:node id="${grandChildNode.getNodeId()}" name="${grandChildNode.title}">
                            <dyxml:${grandChildNode.href.getDyxmlRefType()} href="../${grandChildNode.href.getPath()}"
                            tid="${grandChildNode.href.id}" version="${grandChildNode.href.version}" xml:lang="${grandChildNode.href.xmlLang}"/>
                        </dyxml:node>
                        </#list>
                    <#else>
                    <dyxml:${innerNode.href.getDyxmlRefType()} href="../${innerNode.href.getPath()}" tid="${innerNode.href.id}" version="${innerNode.href.version}" xml:lang="${innerNode.href.xmlLang}"/>
                    </#if>
                </dyxml:node>
                </#list>
            <#else>
                <dyxml:${outerNode.href.getDyxmlRefType()} href="../${outerNode.href.getPath()}" tid="${outerNode.href.id}" version="${outerNode.href.version}" xml:lang="${outerNode.href.xmlLang}"/>
            </#if>
        </dyxml:node>
        </#list>
    </dyxml:root>
```

When innerNode.children size is greater than 0, then the nested list for displaying grandChildNodes gets executed. However in cases where innerNode.children size is 0, the corresponding else part never gets executed. The following else is not being rendered in the created xml file -

```
<#else>
    <dyxml:${innerNode.href.getDyxmlRefType()} href="../${innerNode.href.getPath()}" tid="${innerNode.href.id}" version="${innerNode.href.version}" xml:lang="${innerNode.href.xmlLang}"/>
</#if>
```

I have debugged the data and verified for the cases where innerNode.children is 0, the else part should ideally get executed. Please let me know what I might be missing. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but note that instead of things like `innerNode.href.getDyxmlRefType()` you can and should simply write `innerNode.href.dyxmlRefType`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is certainly that the `#if` condition uses `outerNode?size` instead of `outerNode.children?size`, while you are listing  `outerNode.children`.